# Alternative to com.google.common.io.ByteArrayDataInput?

Tags: java, guava

I'm currently using `com.google.common.io.ByteArrayDataInput` in my code. What I'm writing is a sort of loader for a binary file. Unfortunately, ByteArrayDataInput does not provide the information how many bytes left in its internal byte array. Is there any alternative to this class that provides such infomation? I know I can write my own wrapper class for `com.google.common.io.ByteArrayDataInput`, but I'd like to avoid that.

**EDIT**

The problem is that the reference to my `com.google.common.io.ByteArrayDataInput` instance is passed very deeply through a chain of methods. It looks like this:

`loadA(ByteArrayDataInput in)` invokes `loadB(in)` which invokes `loadC(in);` and so forth..

every of loadX() methods reads something from `in`. And I would like to invoke `ByteArrayDataInput.readFully()` method in `loadC()` and I would like to check at that level how many bytes left to read. To achieve that with this class I would need to pass bytesLeft info through all the `loadX()` methods.

Comment: Well, you know the file size, if you just count the bytes already read you get the bytes left! Which is the implementing class you are using?

Comment: Help me out here - other than not throwing exceptions, what does ByteArrayDataInput offer that an ObjectInputStream wrapping a ByteArrayInputStream does not?  Maybe I just need my morning coffee, but I don't see any meaningful differences.

Comment: @cutchin: you're right... I'm heavily using methods such as: readByte(), readUnsignedByte(), readShort(), readUnsignedShort() from ByteArrayDataInput. but I can see them in ObjectInputStream class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to prepare my own wrapper class for Guava `ByteArrayDataInputWrapper`. 
It adds a new method `getAvailable()` which returns the number of bytes left to read.

```
public class ByteArrayDataInputWrapper implements ByteArrayDataInput {

    private static final int INT_LENGTH = 4;
    private static final int FLOAT_LENGTH = 4;  
    private static final int LONG_LENGTH = 8;
    private static final int DOUBLE_LENGTH = 8; 

    private ByteArrayDataInput in;
    private int available;

    public ByteArrayDataInputWrapper(byte[] binary) {
        if (binary != null) {
            in = ByteStreams.newDataInput(binary);
            available = binary.length;
        }
    }

    public int getAvailable() {
        return available;
    }   

    @Override
    public void readFully(byte[] b) {
        in.readFully(b);
        available -= b.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void readFully(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
        in.readFully(b, off, len);
        available -= len;
    }

    @Override
    public int skipBytes(int n) {
        int skipped = in.skipBytes(n);
        available -= skipped;
        return skipped;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean readBoolean() {
        boolean result = in.readBoolean();
        available--;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public byte readByte() {
        byte result = in.readByte();
        available--;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int readUnsignedByte() {
        int result = in.readUnsignedByte();
        available--;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public short readShort() { 
        short result = in.readShort(); 
        available -= 2;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int readUnsignedShort() {
        int result = in.readUnsignedShort();
        available -= 2;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public char readChar() {
        char result = in.readChar();
        available -= 2;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int readInt() {
        int result = in.readInt();
        available -= INT_LENGTH;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public long readLong() {
        long result = in.readLong();
        available -= LONG_LENGTH;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public float readFloat() {
        float result = in.readFloat();
        available -= FLOAT_LENGTH;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public double readDouble() {
        double result = in.readDouble();
        available -= DOUBLE_LENGTH;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String readLine() {
        String result = in.readLine();
        if (result != null) {
            available -= result.length();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String readUTF() {
        String result = in.readUTF();
        if (result != null) {
            available -= result.length();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

ByteArrayInputStream's available method returns the number of bytes left in the array according to the [source](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-5.0/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.java.html).  Wrapping that in an [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) would seem to give you just about the same functionality.  ObjectInputStream's available() method returns available() from the underlying input stream without doing any processing.

Comment: There's one issue with your approach. ObjectInputStream should go together with ObjectOutputStream and I don't want such serialization in my code. I'm simply getting a raw array of bytes.

Comment: Actually, DataInputStream has mostly the same methods as well, and isn't tied to anything serialization-related.  It uses "modified UTF-8" which is mostly relevant if you have nulls in your strings.  I'm not certain if that's the same as the Guava library.

Comment: Well, I really thought ObjectInputStream would resolve my problems, however, I ran into other issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381521/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header