# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header?

Tags: java

This is the continuation of [Alternative to com.google.common.io.ByteArrayDataInput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378862/alternative-to-com-google-common-io-bytearraydatainput)

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
public String convertToXml(final byte[] binary) {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(binary);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(bais);
        ObjectInputStream ois = null; 
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            throw new ConversionException("Unable to instantiate ObjectInputStream", e1);
        }
     // ...
}
```

but I keep getting:

```
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 1278D4DB
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:782)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:279)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us how you are writing the ObjectOutputStream? I wouldn't buffer a byte array. The error indicates the data wasn't written by an ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Ok, I'm starting to understand... I'm not using OjectOutputStream at all. What I'm getting is simply a raw array of bytes from other system.

Comment: Are you sure it's in the Java serialisation format.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: My mistake. I forgot what is the actual purpose of ObjectInputStream.

Comment: @LukaszBaran Could you solve this error?